# Array with different data types in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two arrays one is string and other in integer in JavaScript and  I want an object in this form

```
[["a",1],["b",2],["c",3]]
```

Please help how I create this object

Edit: Practical example of where this is needed...https://www.cssscript.com/creating-funnel-charts-using-svg-and-d3-js-d3-funnel/

Comment: Say what? That really doesn't make much sense I'm afraid...

Comment: Dear I want to create this object with the help of string and integer array

Comment: I'm sorry, we're all out of objects, but they will be back in stock next week ?

Comment: But how are you mapping things, and that's an array, not an object.

Comment: Dear, have some manners when you ask for help. Show what you have done already and what you need it for.

Comment: In short I need output in this form

Comment: @benm then why didn't you vote to close?

Comment: @JanDvorak because I like to give askers an opportunity to improve their question before sealing its fate...

Comment: Dear its not a way to encourage peoples you should be friendly

Comment: @BenM Still waiting for some improvements? ;D

Comment: @wared then do it yourself.

Comment: @Billi After you dear poster, you can really thank dystroy for reading between the lines :D

Comment: @wared I am really thankful to you also.

Comment: Too bad that you were not as generous into your question :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one of the many possible solutions :

```
var a1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var a2 = [1, 2, 3];
var a3 = a1.map(function(e,i){ return [e,a2[i]] });
```

This makes `[["a",1],["b",2],["c",3]]`.

See [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

---

If what you want is an object (an "associative array") like `{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`

then it's a little more interesting :

```
var a1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var a2 = [1, 2, 3];
var a3 = a1.reduce(function(r,e,i){ r[e]=a2[i]; return r }, {});
```

See [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: still getting the data in the form of arrays. :(

Comment: Well... 1) an array is an object 2) you asked for an array in the code in your question...

Comment: And then just do `JSON.stringify(a3);` if you want a string...

Comment: @Billi Is the new code I give in my answer what you're looking for ?

Comment: var a3 = a1.map(function(e,i){ return [e,a2[i]] }); is working fine for me. Thanks for the help rather than discouraging like others